# java development kit error when i am run .exe file

Tags: java

I have downloaded the Netbeans installer on my Windows 10 system . I encountered the following JDK problem during the install process (after I ran the installer, `netbeans-8.1-windows.exe`).

> Java SE developmet kit is not found on this computer.<-- this is my problem.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What does JavaScript have to do with Java.

Answer (score 0):

You need the JDK in order to develop using Java. Here is the link to download:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

After downloading and installing the JDK, you will be to solve the problem you have.